# dynamic input text field not changing with radio button in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, razor

As seen in code, I have two dynamic test input fields, one with radio button and another with check box.

The one with check box is working, while the with radio button is not. Can somebody help what is broken here?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).parent().children('div.max_tickets').show();
      else $(this).parent().children('div.max_tickets').hide();
    }).change();
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
          valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
          invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
          validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
          first_name: {
            validators: {
              stringLength: {
                min: 2,
              },
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'your first name'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        $('#success_message').slideDown({
          opacity: "show"
        }, "slow")
        $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(e.target);

        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        }, 'json');
      });
  });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function() {
      if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
        $("#dvPassport").show();
      } else {
        $("#dvPassport").hide();
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10" style="padding: 0; height:20%;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <span>Do you have Passport?</span>
      <label for="chkYes">
        <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" /> Yes
      </label>
      <label for="chkNo">
        <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" /> No
      </label>
      <hr />
      <div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
        Passport Number:
        <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
      </div>
      <form action="">
        <div id="opwp_woo_tickets">
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][enable]">
            <div class="max_tickets">
              <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div class="container">
      <form class="well form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems here:

1. Your function for checking the radio inputs does not need to be in a separate `<script>` tag and should be inside your main `$(document).ready` function.
2. Don't put the `$("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function(){})` inside another "function".

With these changes to your code you can see that the radio responds as it should:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {

      //Moved inside $(document).ready()
      $("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function() { 
        if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {               
          $("#dvPassport").show();           
        } else {               
          $("#dvPassport").hide();           
        }       
      });

      $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).parent().children('div.max_tickets').show();
        else $(this).parent().children('div.max_tickets').hide();
      }).change();
      $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
          feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
          },
          fields: {
            first_name: {
              validators: {
                stringLength: {
                  min: 2,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                  message: 'your first name'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
          $('#success_message').slideDown({
            opacity: "show"
          }, "slow")
          $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
          e.preventDefault();
          var $form = $(e.target);

          var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

          $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            console.log(result);
          }, 'json');
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10" style="padding: 0; height:20%;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <span>Do you have Passport?</span>
      <label for="chkYes">
        <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" />Yes
      </label>
      <label for="chkNo">
        <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" />No
      </label>
      <hr />
      <div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
        Passport Number:
        <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
      </div>

      <form action="">
        <div id="opwp_woo_tickets">
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][enable]">
            <div class="max_tickets">
              <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->


    <div class="container">

      <form class="well form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
        <fieldset>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move this code to $(document).ready function. https://jsfiddle.net/6qvy102s/

```
     $("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function () {
                if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#dvPassport").show();
                } else {
                    $("#dvPassport").hide();
                }           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function () {
        if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
            $("#dvPassport").show();
        } else {
            $("#dvPassport").hide();
        }
    });
});
```